# MD5 varchar to varbinary in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

I have a problem with Codeigniter.
I'm trying to encrypt a password using md5 and then save the password in a varbinary field

```
$password    = md5($this->input->post('password', TRUE));
```

The problem I see is this:

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

I researched a lot and the problem is as follows.

an encrypted password in php:

```
c832591f90dced4b7c11e7dbcf2e5a68
```

an encrypted password in sql query:

```
SELECT HashBytes('MD5','password')
result: 0x5F4DCC3B5AA765D61D8327DEB882CF99
```

Then try to do the following to save the MD5 string in a varbinary column

```
$password1    = md5($this->input->post('password', TRUE));
$password2    = strtoupper($password1);
$password     = '0x'.$password2
```

But obviously it did not work. As I can save a MD5 string in a varbinary column in SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: try to change it to $password= md5($this->input->post('password')); and echo it to see what is the result

Comment: Hi, I've already done that. Look above, I put the encrypted string as seen